# How to calculate the price of a fully unlocked legacy weapon?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

I need to calculate the total sell value of fully unlocked legacy weapons; for example, a Faithful Avenger with all legacy rituals completed.
Its non-legacy price is 4330gp, and the cost of the rituals are 1500, 13,000 and 39,000 gp, but it's not worth *just* 57830 gp, or is it?
I'd like some guidelines that I can follow to calculate the value of any of these.

---

I know that it will lose its legacy abilities if it changes hands so it can't actually be sold like that, but that's not why I want it:

I'm DMing a campaign in 3.5, and after they tackled the main objective, they set their next objective themselves. The thing about it is that it was impossible to do that in their current level (they want to destroy the Wall of the Faithless, if you need to know), so I agreed on taking them to epic levels.

Since there was a lot of disparity in levels and treasure between the party (because of some of them showing up every time and the rest only now and then and stuff like that), I took this as an opportunity to make them all start in the same page, so I set them all to level up their characters to the same level and choose equipment so that the value of everything they own, including what they already had, is worth the same amount of money; so I need to calculate how much the stuff they have is worth so each of them can know how much they can spend.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Good question, looking forward to seeing the answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, a weapon of legacy can only be built as a result of events in game. If you want to let them purchase it, though, use the total price that you've given in the original post. When the player advances using a weapon of legacy, they gain a set of penalties, such as BAB reductions, reduced skill points, and so forth. These help offset the relatively low cost of the item. Ensure that the player also incorporates these penalties into the character build. IMHO, it isn't necessary to tinker with the price. If you feel like a particular power or set of powers given by the item is unbalancing, you should adjust the price using equivalent magic item creation from the core rules as a guideline, but reduce it by some factor (25 or 50%?) to account for the penalty.

I'd also suggest making them come up with an explanation for the item - an important event that defined it as an item of legacy - if they haven't already.

Comment: I'm not really considering to let them purchase it, I just want to be able to calculate how much what they already have is worth. They already found and unlocked them already in the first part of the game, so they don't really need to explain anything to me. I just have a gut feeling that ~60k is too small a value for these kinds of weapon (specifically, the ones they have are from the Nine Swords), but "winging it" leaves a rotten taste in my mouth. Hence why I'm here asking for guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

A guideline I use when giving out magical gear is that I always round up a good deal, so I'd say it's more at the range of 75k gold pieces (58k+5k each for the three rituals is how I'd calculate it, then round it up for clean numbers), just to make things speedier and more convenient. My method's rather arbitrary, but I feel that it helps keep things smooth.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did in the end: Let's forget for a second monetary value and focus on intrinsic value instead. The full value of the weapon would be equal to the base non-legacy weapon + the full gp spent on the rituals + the 3 legacy feats - the personal cost.

Converting the first two to a gp cost is easy, I did exactly that in the original post.  For the Faithful Avenger, this partial cost is 57,830 gp.

Then we got the 3 feats. This is a little harder. I used [this list](http://home.comcast.net/~ftm3/JHtB/feats.html) as a guide, and I figure that the approximate cost of a feat that's active only when wielding a particular weapon is more or less 5,000 gp. The cost is now 72,830 gp.

Now for the hardest part. I have to somehow calculate the gp value of the personal cost. Continuing with the example of the FA, this would be -2 Attack, -4 Fort and -12 HP. I kinda gave up here and decided to just cancel the feat cost with this... it will make calculating the rest of them a lot easier too.